# Jquery mobile : loading spinner not working in JQM 1.4.4

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQM 1.4.4 and seeking for the loading message spinner.
When i was using JQM 1.2 it was working  fine with `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "No spinner", true);`
But the same method is not working on JQM 1.4.4.

I am using phonegap 3.4 with JQM 1.4.4 on android.

Comment: Its not duplicate, the OP would like to hide the spinner also. The Other Question does not reflect that. :))

Comment: @Tasos read the dupe answer well :) $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); and $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); are replaced by $.mobile.loading('show'); and $.mobile.loading('hide'); as of jQuery Mobile 1.3.2.

Comment: @omar. Yeah i saw that, but I just went by the ("No spinner", true) in the question. :)) no worries

Answer (score 3):

This is the new Loader Mehod to show it in 1.4. You need  **textonly: true** in the options if you want to hide the spinner. If you want to show it then take it out

To show the Loader

```
$.mobile.loading( "show", {
  text: "Loading",
  textonly: true,
  textVisible: true,
  theme: "z",
  html: ""
})
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/6y23pua7/

To hide it `$.mobile.loading( "hide" )`

Comment: I am using it for ajax call.. It is still not working..

Comment: before your ajax call show it and after your ajax call has completed the work hide it. Also the loader has the highest z-index of (9999999;) make sure your page has a lower z-index

Comment: It is working only in : `$(document).on("pageshow","#user_home",function(e){ $.mobile.loading( "show", {
  text: "Loading",
  textonly: true,
  textVisible: true,
  theme: "z",
  html: ""
}) })` and not outside the $(document).on();